# Facing errors when creating index

Tags: mysql, indexing, datadirectory

I've been facing trouble creating a first index for my table. Whether I do:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX(column(4));
```

or

```
CREATE INDEX column ON table (column(20));
```

I get,

> ERROR 1210 (HY000): Incorrect arguments to DATA DIRECTORY

Am I doing something wrong with the naming of the table? Or the prefix length? Changing either of those, making the index name a unique name or the name of the column, etc, doesn't eliminate the error. Some of the columns are VARCHAR, one is YEAR, and contain either text strings or numbers if that helps.

Comment: Do you have a bad DATA DIRECTORY set? You can check with `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`table\``.

Comment: I don't think so, at least. I ran that command and got my table description:

Comment: I ran that command and got my table description---


    | current_members | CREATE TABLE `current_members` (
  `fname` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gpa` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grad_year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `major` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 DATA DIRECTORY='./members/' INDEX DIRECTORY='./members/' |


---What would a bad data directory set look like?